# Unique constraint on different columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint, unique-constraint

I'm trying to make a table to store the edges of a directed graph, but want to avoid duplicate edges in both directions.
I can of course make it one direction :

```
CREATE TABLE edge (parent integer, child integer, UNIQUE(parent, child));
```

But how can I make sure that I also don't allow a new (parent, child) that already exists as (child, parent) ?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using [`GREATEST` and `LEAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-conditional.html#functions-greatest-least)

Essentially, if we can sort of the columns in the index, we can ensure that the duplicate entry causes a collision and a constraint violation this is because `sort(5,2) = sort(2,5)`. Because there is no `sort`, we use `greatest` and `least`.

```
CREATE TABLE edge (
  parent int,
  child  int
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
  ON edge ( greatest(parent,child), least(parent,child) );

INSERT INTO edge(parent,child)
VALUES (42,7), (42,9), (5,7);

INSERT INTO edge(parent,child)
VALUES (7,42);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "edge_greatest_least_idx"
DETAIL:  Key ((GREATEST(parent, child)), (LEAST(parent, child)))=(42, 7) already exists.
```

Comment: Thanks ! the greatest / least was the thing I was apparently too stupid for.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - check out my answer! What's your assessment of performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

**You can also do this: (for positive `INTEGER`s [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGW8i1VXGDSjB1SHC1mJVV/0))**

```
CREATE TABLE edge 
(
  parent int NOT NULL,
  child  int NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ed_uq_ix ON edge (ABS(parent - child), (parent * child));
```

**Non conflicting records:**

```
INSERT INTO edge(parent,child) VALUES (42,7), (42,9), (5,7); -- succeeds
```

**BUT:**

```
INSERT INTO edge VALUES (9, 42);  -- fails!
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's faster -- and I'm not sure the speed matters on this kind of operation, but it won't work on more than 100k parent/child rows without growing to bigint. For instance, run your create DDL and then run `INSERT INTO edge(parent,child) VALUES (1e5, 1e5);` My example works up until 2,147,483,647 (>1e9) which is the full range of ints.

Comment: Won't PostgreSQL just `CAST` anyway? I'm not sure any system would cope with 2^32 edges?

Comment: I think you're missing what I'm saying. In a normal serial column, you can handle `2^31-1` rows and the primary key can handle `2^32` rows. Both of those are *usually* far more rows than needed. In your index, you can only handle 46340 rows. Why? Because your algorithm is p*c assuming p=c, you can exhaust that range in 46,341. I find it possible to have more than 46,341 edges. So the difference between your range and my range is `(2^31-1) - sqrt(2^31-1)` you have to value the performance difference, if anything, that much; if you can only support 46,341 rows - does it matter?

Comment: Besides the other reasons - already mentioned by Evan and a_horse_with_no_name - this has an issue with negative ids as well. It doesn't allow both `(-5,1)` and `(-1,5)` for example.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ edited to deal with your concerns! Hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have removed the reference to performance - on reflection, it probably wouldn't be faster.